# C# Outlook 2010 Custom Ribbon Button - Get New Item ID?

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

Is it possible to access the current new item Id, (pre-creation) from a custom ribbon button action?

For example, I have created a new button within the Appointment Tab, so when someone creates a new appointment or meeting, my button is there on the right hand side of the ribbon. I have that wired up to a Click event. What I want to do here, is somehow access some sort of identifier to the currently being composed appointment/meeting, when that button is clicked.

[image]

So I'm wondering;
 - does outlook create some sort of ID for the message, even before clicking 'Send' or 'Save' ? And if so is this obtainable?

EDIT:
Just thought I'd add, an alternative/workaround for me would be if I could somehow bind or add data to the appointment, which I could then retrieve through some sort of listener when the appointment gets created (which I would then have the ID for). I'm hoping this will definitely be possible given the other ribbon buttons perform actions on the appointment when it's created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RibbonControl` is passed as an argument to your event handler. `RibbonControl.Context` will be the `Inspector` object (or `Explorer` if your button is on the Explorer ribbon). Use the `Inspector.CurrentItem` property to retrieve the item.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. It doesn't provide the EntryID, but I didn't think it would anyway - this at least provides me with access to the data they have filled in for the appointment. I'm now hoping there's some sort of property setter which I can use as my own ID to tie the two systems together. Thanks!

Comment: You can use AppointmentItem.EntryID, but it is available only after the item is saved.